# Texas Stellaris Launchpad EK-LMF120XL 4 Digit Seven Segment Display

Tags: microcontroller, launchpad

I'm working on make a 4 digit counter starting from 0 to 999. I'm using port D for which digit is gonna be writen and port B for which seven segment number is gonna display.

I'm using 4 digit commond anode display. 330ohm for seven segment number , 10K for transistors and transistors connected to Port D (PD0,PD1,PD2,PD3). I used transistor for decide which digit is gonna be writen. Here is my code down below.

```
    #include <stdint.h>
#include "inc/lm4f120h5qr.h"

#include "inc/hw_ints.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/timer.h"

static inline void disable_interrupts() {
    asm("CPSID I");
}

static inline void enable_interrupts() {
    asm("CPSIE I");
}

static inline void wait_for_interrupt() {
    asm("WFI");
}

void init_port_B() {
    volatile unsigned long delay;
    SYSCTL_RCGC2_R |= SYSCTL_RCGC2_GPIOB;
    delay = SYSCTL_RCGC2_R;
    GPIO_PORTB_DIR_R |= 0xFF;
    GPIO_PORTB_AFSEL_R &= ~0xFF;
    GPIO_PORTB_DEN_R |= 0xFF;
}

void init_port_D() {
    volatile unsigned long delay;
    SYSCTL_RCGC2_R |= SYSCTL_RCGC2_GPIOD; // activate port D
    delay = SYSCTL_RCGC2_R;     // allow time for clock to stabilize
    GPIO_PORTD_DIR_R |= 0x0F;   // make PD3-0 out
    GPIO_PORTD_AFSEL_R &= ~0x0F; // regular port function
    GPIO_PORTD_DEN_R |= 0x0F;   // enable digital I/O on PD3-0
}

void init_timer_0(unsigned int period) {
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_TIMER0);

    TimerConfigure(TIMER0_BASE, TIMER_CFG_PERIODIC);
    TimerLoadSet(TIMER0_BASE, TIMER_A, period);

    IntEnable(INT_TIMER0A);
    TimerIntEnable(TIMER0_BASE, TIMER_TIMA_TIMEOUT);

    TimerEnable(TIMER0_BASE, TIMER_A);
}

volatile int flag_ekran_guncelle = 0;

void timer_0_handler() {
    TimerIntClear(TIMER0_BASE, TIMER_TIMA_TIMEOUT); // clear time interrupt

    flag_ekran_guncelle = 1;
}

void SysTick_Init(unsigned long period) {
    NVIC_ST_CTRL_R = 0;         // disable SysTick during setup
    NVIC_ST_RELOAD_R = period - 1;      // reload value
    NVIC_ST_CURRENT_R = 0;      // any write to current clears it
    NVIC_SYS_PRI3_R = (NVIC_SYS_PRI3_R & 0x00FFFFFF) | 0x40000000; // priority 2
    NVIC_ST_CTRL_R = 0x07; // enable SysTick with core clock and interrupts
    // enable interrupts after all initialization is finished
}

// 1 saniyedeki systick kesmesi sayisi
#define SYSTICK_HZ 100
// baslangictan itibaren olusan systick kesmesi sayisi
uint32_t systick_count = 0;

volatile int flag_sayi_arttir = 0;

void systick_handler() {
    systick_count++;

    // 0.1 saniyede bir sayiyi arttirma flagini 1 yap
    if ((systick_count % (SYSTICK_HZ / 10)) == 0)
     flag_sayi_arttir = 1;
}

// 0'dan 9'a kadar olan sayilarin seven segment kodlari
// bit sirasi: g f e d c b a
uint8_t kodlar[10] = {

        0xC0,
        0XF9,
        0XA4,
        0XB0,
        0X99,
        0X92,
        0X83,
        0XF8,
        0x80,
        0x98
   /*0b0111111,
    0b0000110,
    0b1011011,
    0b1001111,
    0b1100110,
    0b1101101,
    0b1111101,
    0b0000111,
    0b1111111,
    0b1101111*/

};

int ekran_guncelle_no = 0;
void ekran_guncelle(int sayi) {
    ekran_guncelle_no = (ekran_guncelle_no + 1) % 4; // guncellenen ekranin numarasini bir arttir

    if (ekran_guncelle_no == 0) {
     int birler = sayi % 10;
    GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R |= 0b1111; // hepsini kapat
    GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R &= ~0b0001;
    GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R = kodlar[birler];
    // birler basamagini aktiflestir
    } else if (ekran_guncelle_no == 1) {
     int onlar = (sayi / 10) % 10;
    GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R |= 0b1111; // hepsini kapat
    GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R &= ~0b0010;
    GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R = kodlar[onlar];// onlar basamagini aktiflestir
    }if (ekran_guncelle_no == 2) {
     int yuzler = (sayi / 100) % 10;
    GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R |= 0b1111; // hepsini kapat
    GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R &= ~0b0100;
    GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R = kodlar[yuzler];// yuzler basamagini aktiflestir
    } else if (ekran_guncelle_no == 3) {
     int binler = (sayi / 1000) % 10;
    GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R |= 0b1111; // hepsini kapat
    GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R &= ~0b1000;
    GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R = kodlar[binler];// binler basamagini aktiflestir
    }
}

int main() {

    disable_interrupts();
    init_port_B();
    init_port_D();
    init_timer_0(SysCtlClockGet() / 200);
    SysTick_Init(1600000);

    enable_interrupts();

    int sayi = 1234;

    while (1) {
     if (flag_ekran_guncelle == 1) {
         flag_ekran_guncelle = 0;
         ekran_guncelle(sayi);
     }

     if (flag_sayi_arttir == 1) {
         flag_sayi_arttir = 0;
         sayi++;
     }

     wait_for_interrupt();
    }
}
```

I don't know where is the wrong this code but it is not working well. If you think code was right , it might be electronic connection problem. So, if you think this way please tell me how can I connect 4 digit seven segment to my launchpad correctly.

Comment: Have you managed to blink just blink a single LED, understanding what each line of code does? What toolchain do you use, your program looks a fair bit different from what I would expect.

Comment: It's been a while for me to remember exact details, but some GPIO registers come with a "lock register". You probably want to check the datasheet for those. For example to enable GPIOF I had to fiddle with: ROM_SysCtlPeripheralEnable( SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF ); GPIO_PORTF_LOCK_R; GPIO_PORTF_CR_R and GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R. Check the datasheet for details. Try to control each single pin first before trying to control the whole display. The controller you picked is a fairly complex.

Answer (score 1):

I moved to 2 pin (PD3,PD4) to another pin (PE1,PE2) and changed the code that way. It worked. I don't know why but it works for now very well.